# Jenkins using WebHook automated

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

i have big problem which i cannot solve already try two days, and i wasted, so i register here please , can you give advice or solve this problem. My main computer where i programming using windows 10 IDE Eclipse, i have another computer which i want to have server , i installed everything correctly i mean tomcat web container. Yes i am new to this, and i want to learn job specific way. So i installed on server jenkins by own. I want that when i push code from local to gitHub repository, jenkins detects that and trigger to build. But what i get is "We couldn’t deliver this payload: Service Timeout " from GitHub , i using this payload  http://192.168.0.11:8080/github-webhook/ maybe here problem? But in Jenkins i got this error: "There are some problems while registering/removing hooks for GitHub. There is no credentials with admin access to manage hooks on GitHub RepositoryName[host=github.com,username=AndriusAlimas,repository=Jenkinsproject1]" I think i done credential, i am very confuse, i dont know where to start.

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Method POST required
 at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponses.error(HttpResponses.java:83)

Comment: what is this address ? looks like a private address which is not accessible from public internet ( github )